# How to make object of match element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list of pax in my HTML. I need to make an object containing pax type and their count. for instance: `{adult:3, child:2}` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6EAh4/3/)

```
var obj='{';
$('.pax').find('div').each(function(i,val){
   var pax= $(this).text();
   obj+= $(this).text();
        obj+=':';
        obj+=i;
        obj+=','

})

obj+="}"
```

console.log(obj)

Comment: Please, NEVER create JSON using string functions...

Comment: @ThiefMaster now you have to explain to OP why   ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var obj = {};

$('.pax').find('div').each(function (i, val) {
    var pax = $.trim($(this).text());
    obj[pax] = (obj[pax] || 0) + 1;
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9d9nZ/)

Then use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) if you want a string representation of the value

Answer (score 5):

```
var obj = {};
$('.pax div').each(function(i) {
    var pax = $(this).text();
    obj[pax] = i;
});
```

However, with your current markup this doesn't make any sense - objects cannot have multiple values for the same key unless you store an array:

```
var obj = {};
$('.pax div').each(function(i) {
    var pax = $(this).text();
    if (!(pax in obj)) {
        obj[pax] = [];
    }
    obj[pax].push(i);
});
```

If you don't need the indexes but the count for each type, see [this answer instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20720797/298479).

If you need a JSON string in the end, use `JSON.stringify(obj)`.

Comment: don't think what the OP is looking for is the last index of the text

Comment: That's why I included the second code block. But yeah the OP's question is very vague (thanks for reminding me to downvote it ;p) what he actually wants..

Comment: I think `I need to make an object containing pax type and their count` is clear enough

Comment: It's look like an array, not an object

Comment: Ah yeah, didn't see that. Yay for posting code that does something completely different...